# PHP > SOAP > Response array missing a value

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I have a SOAP API and in PHP when I use *print_r()* to print the response I get all values except of one!

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Vmatcher] => stdClass Object
        (
            [RAB] => 619876
            [MCC] => Rejected
            [TRF] => 3999c2
            [FDX] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [RKM] => 23.3788140758
                    [TMK] => 20.99
                    [PDF] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [RAM] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [FD] => 8014.46521889
                                    [MG] => 35
                                )
                        )
                )
            [Status] => Processing
        )
)
```

I am missing one value after

```
[RKM] => 23.3788140758
```

If I try to see the response like this `echo htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse())  . "\n";`

I get the missing value!

```
<b:RKM>23.378814075828778</b:RKM>
<b:CCC>400995</b:CCC>
<b:TMK>20.99</b:TMK>
```

I should get `<b:CCC>400995</b:CCC>` in the array,
What do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: whats the responce string before you convert it?

Comment: What's in your WSDL?  Maybe `CCC` is not in the WSDL so it is quietly ignored even though it is in the XML.

Comment: @Dagon : I did not understand your question

Comment: @BareNakedCoder : No , it have when I run it on SOAPUI and when I echo htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse())  . "\n"; I get it

Comment: I have a very similar situation but both `print_r` as well as `__getLastResponse` has one missing value. The server side log shows that the response from the server is sending the value that is missing in the client side. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the Issue,

If you face this issue! check the WSDL file!

In my case it was an old file and not updated! 
( also make sure that there is no WSDL cashing,so your SOAP did not request the old file after updaing it)